# PHP - Question about specifying variable with global scope outside of a function

Tags: php, global-variables

I understand that if you declare a variable within a php function with the 'global' keyword it will reference a variable declared outside the function, but why would a php programmer want to declare a variable outside of a function scope as 'global?' Thanks!

I understand what this does:

```
<?
$a = 1;
function $boo() {
    global $a;
    echo $a;
}
?>
```

But what I'm getting at is why would I want to do this?

```
<?
global $a;
function $boo() {
    //foo
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with php scope
If you have file a.php that has a class like this

```
<?
class test()
{
  function test()
  {
    include('b.php');
  }
}
?>
```

and a file b.php

```
<?
$a = 1;
?>
```

Then $a will only be accessible in the scope of function test()

if you have `global $a` in b.php, $a then becomes a global variable

here's the php doc about it : http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Good point. Although that is basically the same situation as the asker originally presented. All includes/requires are executed within the scope the include statement is in, so you're still within a function, and using it to break out of the function scope. The include just makes it less transparent what's going on.

Comment: Yes but that is the only reason why you would see a global keyword in the main scope of a php file (ie it's included elsewhere and hence need the global to break out of the scope).

Comment: ^This may be what's happening somewhere in the rest of this code. I do agree that this is can be unclear and confusing.

Comment: Good explanation. So don't do globals people, it's up there with goto's ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would want to do that. For all intents and purposes (unless I am very, very much mistaken) this is exactly the same as just:

```
<?
var $a;
function $boo() {
  // foo
}
?>
```

Which in turn is the very same as

```
<?
function $boo() {
  // foo
}
?>
```

because you generally don't have to instantiate your variables in PHP.

Very curious why you're using variably-named functions though? (`function $boo() {}` )

Comment: Yeah I'm analyzing someone else's code and I'm trying to understand what's going on. I found this and I couldn't understand why it was being done.

Comment: Wow... in that case... good luck! If they do this kind of thing, you're going to need it. (legacy codebases.. the joy, the suffering!)

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMHO the use of global variables is a poor programming practice. It can cause unintended side-effects in your program which are hard to debug, and makes it harder to maintain.

Comment: While a very valid observation, this does not answer the question.

Comment: You are right. The PHP parser should throw a syntax error in this case, but it doesn't (surprise, surprise).